# Image Mouseover fade In/Out JQUERY ONLY, Responsive

Tags: jquery, html, hover, mouseover, fade

I've searched for over 6 hours and haven't found what I'm looking for at all. I have your typical mouseover. An image, you hover over it and it changes to a different image, unhover and it goes back to the image it was. I want exactly that, but with a fade to it. I thought it would be simple but apparently not. I DO NOT want CSS. It is not responsive. My images change size based on the screen size (i'm using foundation 4). I have code that works perfectly (responsive) but there is no fade. If I could get someone to tell me how to add a fade to my code that would be great because quite frankly: I don't get how to. Here is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

if (document.images) {
    productbuttonup = new Image();
    productbuttonup.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100";
    productbuttondown = new Image();
    productbuttondown.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100/eeeeee";

    aboutbuttonup = new Image();
    aboutbuttonup.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100/333333";
    aboutbuttondown = new Image();
    aboutbuttondown.src = "http://placehold.it/100x100/777777";
}

function buttondown(buttonname) {
    if (document.images) {
        document[buttonname].src = eval(buttonname + "down.src");
    }
}

function buttonup(buttonname) {
    if (document.images) {
        document[buttonname].src = eval(buttonname + "up.src");
    }
}

</script>
```

And of course the html:

```
<div class="large-3 columns image"><a href="about.html"
onmouseover="buttondown('productbutton')"
onmouseout="buttonup('productbutton')"><img src="img/product_photography.jpg"   name="productbutton" class="productbutton"></a></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k7Cfs/

Comment: Fiddle added. I'm seeing some console errors you should take a look at.

Comment: thanks @isherwood. I grabbed the script from this tutorial: http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/rollovers.shtml
So I don't quite understand the console errors.

Comment: You're not getting much response because it's not clear 1) what you had working originally, and 2) what you've added since that broke it. It seems like you're throwing a bunch of code at a problem rather than trying to understand the right way to do this. CSS isn't responsive? Wah?

Comment: I'll try to make this more clear... I'm using foundation 4. The code I have above works as a mouseover. I want to add a fade to it. I do NOT want CSS because every CSS answer I've seen requires either layering images on top of each other or background-images both of which break foundation 4's responsive layout. Nothing is broken I just need it to fade :)